# List of <newfloat> with zero caption in text

Tags: floats, lists, captions

new Float type: Illustration

How to make a list of illustrations, with captions in the list,

but for the illustrations to appear in the text with zero captioning - image only.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please explain better, what you intent to do. I don't understand it really. If you need to, paint some little picture. Better, you show us some code of what you have tried for so far. Starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I've tried lopes of different things - the most promising seems to be to define a new float style in which the caption is absent, but i am not experienced enough in Latex to understand how this would be done.

Comment: OK will try some example code - may take a few minutes

Comment: If you want no caption, just leave `\caption{}` away. For the list: I am waiting on what you have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The `caption` package allows you to use

```
\captionlistentry{figure}{my caption}
```

for a caption entry in the list of figures (or any other specified float type) without making a caption in the float itself.

Comment: I have some example code to share, but apparently it's too long.

Comment: I have: \begin{illustration}                  \captionlisentry{List Entry}                     \end{illustration}   with a nice picture etc - it all works except the hyperlink from the list to the illustration does not work - goes to the first page

Comment: any idea how to ensure the hyperlink works in this case?

Comment: @Roderick Never tried the command at all:-) I just guessed caption would have a feature like that and flipped through its manual. If hyperref and caption are not co-operating you could ping their authors and ask....